# transform xml child node values

Tags: c#, xslt

```
 - <SAPAccounts> <SAPAccount ChargeNumber="0FPT15068806"
   WSDescription="CCEC 32 - Rotor Standstill Inspection" /> <SAPAccount
   ChargeNumber="dfgdfgfgg" WSDescription="gfghfghfhhs" />
   </SAPAccounts>
```

---

i want to transform xml into different type of xml. i  want to access multiple child node values.

```
<AddChargeNumberIDto>
<SAP>
<ChargeNumber>0FPT15068806</ChargeNumber>
<Description>CCEC 32 - Rotor Standstill Inspection</Description>
<SAP>
<SAP>
<ChargeNumber>dfgdfgfgg</ChargeNumber>
<Description>gfghfghfhhs</Description>
<SAP>
</AddChargeNumberIDto>
```

Comment: we expect that you start trying yourself. And if you have difficulties with your code, come back, show the code, and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="SAPAccounts">
    <AddChargeNumberIDto>
        <xsl:for-each select="SAPAccount">
            <SAP>
                <ChargeNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ChargeNumber"/>
                </ChargeNumber>
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@WSDescription"/>
                </Description>
            </SAP>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </AddChargeNumberIDto>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will return the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddChargeNumberIDto>
   <SAP>
      <ChargeNumber>0FPT15068806</ChargeNumber>
      <Description>CCEC 32 - Rotor Standstill Inspection</Description>
   </SAP>
   <SAP>
      <ChargeNumber>dfgdfgfgg</ChargeNumber>
      <Description>gfghfghfhhs</Description>
   </SAP>
</AddChargeNumberIDto>
```

---

**Note**: your stylesheet refers to `OpenJobInfo` - but there is no such element in your input.